# c dll use at c# projects

Tags: c#, c

I am calling a dll file from winform at  c#

My dll is supposed to show a console window and get a number that will be transferred back to c# winform,and it does not work.

if I want a dll to return a value it works.

So how can I make my dll work with commands like `printf` or `scanf`, etc.

```
// mydll.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
//#define dll
   extern "C"{  __declspec(dllexport)int  backnum()

   {

    int chek=0,Size=1;
    printf("Hello please  enter a Size for Array max size is  100 \n");

    scanf("%d",&Size);


    return Size;
   }

}
```

Comment: Are you doing this to learn about p/invoke, or do you think this is the best way to solve some problem?  .NET provides the Console class which allows you to do things like this from inside C#.

Comment: this sounds like an utterly terrible ui design, why invoke a command window AND a gui?  Can't you just use a text box? Or use a subprocess to talk to cmd.exe?

Answer (score 1):

> My dll is supposed to show a console window

Which is the rub, you don't create a console window and there isn't any in a Winforms app.  One simple workaround is to right-click your Winforms project in the Solution Explorer window, Properties, Application tab and change the Output type to "Console Application".  Now you get both a console window and your regular form windows.  Or you can call or pinvoke AllocConsole().

You'll be battling other problems when you do this however.  There's a Z-order problem, should the console window be ahead or behind the regular GUI?  If you pinvoke your function from the main thread then your GUI will freeze.  Do consider that maybe it doesn't make too much sense to have both.  Not to the typical user anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> My dll is supposed to show a console window and get a number that will be transferred back to c# winform

If this is indeed a requirement, you're .dll must do two things:

1. Define an API so that the C# call will be able to read back your number (for example, as a return value, or as a C# "out" parameter)
2. Use the Win32 AllocConsole() etc APIs to create a console window

> How can I make my dll work with commands like printf or scanf, etc?

Make sure you include the correct MSVC runtime library .dll wherever you install/run your program (for example, download the Visual C++ Redistributable)